# Populate an array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a search query for `training sessions` that will return me return details of a session, populating data from the `coach (ObjectId)` and the `participants (Array of ObjectIds)`. I can populate the coach but I can not populate the participants. My session schema is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
import { timestamp } from "./plugins/timestamp"
import { User } from './index'

const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  coach: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true, default: "Lacrosse Training Session" },
  participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
SessionSchema.plugin(timestamp);

export const Session = mongoose.model('Session', SessionSchema);
```

And I am trying to populate with:

```
const session = await Session.findById(req.params.id).populate('coach').populate('participants');
```

**Output**
When I use only `populate('coach')`, I get something like:

```
coach: {address: {city: "Joes"}, name: "John John", …} <= <= <= POPULATED
participants: ["5ea43590f105a4188358210f", "5ea43590f105a4188358210e", "5ea43590f105a41883582115"]
```

But when I use `populate('coach').populate('participants')`, I get the same coach, but empty participants (`participants: []`)

Why is that? How can I populate each element of the participants array?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use one of the following:

1-

```
const session = await Session.findById(req.params.id).populate([{ path: 'coach' }, { path: 'participants' }])
```

2-

```
const session = await Session.findById(req.params.id).populate({ path: 'coach' }).populate({ path: 'participants' });
```

also make sure that these participants Ids are already exist in the User collection

Comment: I did not have the user objects with the same id. The data used as input was naming the id field as "id" instead of "_id".

Comment: So, your last comment saved the day. Thank you
"also make sure that these participants Ids are already exist in the User collection"